# gitlab-ci job:rules:if: doesn't work with multiple && operators?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I can't make GitLab CD work properly through the following scenario:

- **%id%-%slug%** - a variety of random dev-line branches.
- **stage** - cumulative review branch that is one step away from being pushed to **main**. The branch is protected, only merge from dev-line branches is allowed.
- **main** - production branch that holds only :latest version of the app. The branch is also protected, only merge from **stage** is allowed.

Merging convention:

1. When devs are done with their particular issues/features in their dev-branches, they submit a merge request to **stage**, that deploys a separate review app for each dev-branch. **Stage** branch accumulates all accepted (merged in) issues.
2. Once release is scoped, a MR is submitted from **stage** to **main**, which supposed to automatically deploy STAGE instance of the app and provide manual task for PROD deployment.

What drives me crazy is that *first part (*deploy review app* job below) is working perfectly* (a job for review app deployment is created, as soon as MR from **dev** to **stage** is submitted), but *second part (the rest two) does not at all* - jobs are not created.

All $VARIABLES exist in all preceding tasks, thus pipeline evaluation presumably should be correct. Tried even playing around with parenthesis grouping, quotes and raw values instead of vars...

Any ideas, what's wrong with my `rules:if` here...?

```yaml
deploy review app:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
  - job: build
    artifacts: true
  - job: unit test
    artifacts: false
  trigger:
    include: 
      - local: .gitlab-ci/deploy-REVIEW.yml
    strategy: depend
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == $PROD_BRANCH
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $STAGE_BRANCH

deploy to STAGE:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
    - job: unit test
      artifacts: false
  trigger:
    include: 
      - local: .gitlab-ci/deploy-STAGE.yml
    strategy: depend
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == $STAGE_BRANCH && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $PROD_BRANCH

deploy to PROD:
  stage: deploy 
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
    - job: unit test
      artifacts: false
    - job: deploy to STAGE
      artifacts: false
  trigger:
    include: 
      - local: .gitlab-ci/deploy-PROD.yml
    strategy: depend
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == $STAGE_BRANCH && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $PROD_BRANCH
  when: manual
```

Comment: Can you please show the actual pipeline run? I'd like to see the context: branches, PR, etc.

Comment: When do you expect to have "the second part" to run? What are the values of `$STAGE_BRANCH` and `$PROD_BRANCH`?

Comment: @VladDX, I'm not sure how to share it properly from that private repo, let's try this way.
Links to all job's logs in order they ran:
https://ctxt.io/2/AACQFONTFQ
Scenarios mentioned are from merging convention from the post.

Comment: You can provide a screenshot of the picture of the pipeline run (with branch name visible). Therefore, we will see what exactly happened. Also, what are the values of `$STAGE_BRANCH` and `$PROD_BRANCH`?

Comment: Here's how it looks like.
https://telegra.ph/pipelines-03-09

From bottom to top:
#801351350 - commit to dev branch;
#801351366 - dev to stage MR;
#801365458 - cherry pick commit to stage;
#801365478 - stage to main MR;

`$STAGE_BRANCH=stage`
`PROD_BRANCH=main`